# Classic ASP - Strange Type Mismatch error

Tags: asp-classic, mismatch

Here is a sample code to simulate the problem:

functs.asp

```
<%
Function SecureStr(Str)
  Dim Res
  Res = Trim(Str)
  If (Res <> "") Then
    Res = Replace(Res, "'", "")
    Res = Replace(Res, ";", "")
    Res = Replace(Res, "=", "")
  End If
  SecureStr = Res
End Function
%>
```

main.asp

```
<%
Option Explicit
Dim Dept
Dept = Request.QueryString("d")
%>
<html>
<body>
<%=Server.Execute(Dept & ".asp")%>
</body>
</html>
```

buy.asp

```
<!--#include file="functs.asp"-->
<%
Dim Name
Name = SecureStr(Request.Form("name"))
%>
BUY CONTENT
```

As you can see, functs.asp is included inside buy.asp file. This way it works without problems (errors) when open http://localhost/main.asp?d=buy. But now I am trying to include functs.asp inside main.asp, like this:

main.asp

```
<%
Option Explicit
Dim Dept
Dept = Request.QueryString("d")
%>
<!--#include file="functs.asp"-->
<html>
<body>
<%=Server.Execute(Dept & ".asp")%>
</body>
</html>
```

buy.asp

```
<%
Dim Name
Name = SecureStr(Request.Form("name"))
%>
BUY CONTENT
```

Well, when included functs.asp inside main.asp, I got an error message:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'SecureStr'
/buy.asp, line 3
```

Please, can someone help me? I really do not know what is going on...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not strange but an expected behaviour of Server.Execute in fact.

From [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3) section:

> If a file is included in the calling page by using #include, the
>   executed .asp will not use it. For example, you may have a subroutine
>   in a file that is included in your calling page, but the executed .asp
>   will not recognize the subroutine name. You must include the file in
>   each executed .asp that requires the subroutine.

Comment: @Paruba you're welcome. there are not too many options. I'd prepare a generic asp file to include with all the functions and declarations will be required in the asp pages to be executed by `Server.Execute`.

Comment: Kul-Tigin, you mean replace the #include file="functs.asp" with Server.Execute("functs.asp") ?

Comment: No. As the docs says, you must include the file in each executed .asp that requires the subroutine. `#include file="functs.asp"` in buy.asp (and so on) for example.

Comment: I already need to include functs.asp in main.asp, and also in each file I opened with server.execute... many duplicated information... but it works, thank you!